How do I make this text appear bold?
How do I make the following text bold? This is on our theme.liquid in shopify that will appear on our product pages when something is out of stock.
product_page_text:"Notify Me When Available",
I've tried < b > and < strong > but this won't work

Are you putting the tags within the quotation marks as shown below:
product_page_text: "<b>Notify Me When Available</b>"

or
product_page_text: "<strong>Notify Me When Available</strong>"


I can't see the tags for some reason in your answer but I've tried both ways

I have updated with the statements in code blocks so it renders the tags, is this the format you are using?
